# Reading (txt , csv) FIle from Azure blob storage using pyspark

Tags: azure, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to read file from Azure blob Storage to Azure HDInsight Cluster using PySpark and getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the Azure portal, try opening the session again. You may be using the Jupyter notebook which you may try to open and then run the commands. It should work fine.